# Two or more threads(may be running on different hosts) tries to insert same data with primary key as randomUUID

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-rds

We have two rds tables.

```
Table_A: row_id = primary_key(randomUUID), product_id = varchar

Table_B: row_id = primary_key(randomUUID), item_id = varchar, mapped_product_id = varchar

Eg: mapping< X, Y>.

mapping is defined as: product_id ----> mapped_product_id. vice versa i.e mapped_product_id ----> product_id. Before insert thread checks whether mappings exists or not.
```

How do I avoid the race condition when two threads(may be running on two different hosts) tries to simultaneously insert same mappings.

Race condition:

1. Thread_1 on host_1 gets mapping X-->Y and Thread_2 on host_2 gets
       same mapping X-->Y.
2. Both threads run following queries at same time:

   ```
   tempTable1 = select * from Table_A where product_id = 'X'

   tempTable2 = select * from Table_B where mapped_product_id = 'Y'

   count_1 = select count(*) from tempTable1 INNER JOIN tempTable2 ON tempTable1.row_id = tempTable2.item_id;

   tempTable11 = select * from Table_A where product_id = 'Y'

   tempTable22 = select * from Table_B where mapped_product_id = 'X'

   count_2 = select count(*) from tempTable11 INNER JOIN tempTable22 ON tempTable11.row_id = tempTable22.item_id;

   if count_1 + count_2 > 0:

   "Mapping already exists". return.

   else
   insert mapping
   ```
3. Now Both threads get count_1 + count_2 = 0 and they inserts
   simultaneously.

   ```
   Following insert queries happens inside a transaction and is run by each thread.
   Thread_1 transaction query:
       randomUUID_1_1 = UUID.randomUUID()
       randomUUID_2_1 = UUID.randomUUID()
       Insert Into Table_A (row_id, product_id) VALUES (randomUUID_1_1, 'X');
       Insert Into Table_B (row_id, item_id, mapped_product_id) VALUES (randomUUID_2_1, randomUUID_1_1, 'Y'); 
   Thread_2 separate transaction query:
       randomUUID_1_2 = UUID.randomUUID()
       randomUUID_2_2 = UUID.randomUUID()
       Insert Into Table_A (row_id, product_id) VALUES (randomUUID_1_2, 'X');
       Insert Into Table_B (row_id, item_id, mapped_product_id) VALUES (randomUUID_2_2, randomUUID_1_2, 'Y');
   ```
4. Both threads ends up inserting the same mapping X--->Y.

Comment: you can use synchronized block or method where record getting inserted,  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243790/java-synchronized-method-how-does-it-work

Comment: Use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Comment: What is the race condition you are talking about? When you use a random UUID and use it as the value in the second table the same UUID will (probably) not be used by the other code/thread which generated a random UUID. That's the point of random UUIDs. What exact problem are you facing when two threads/hosts add data to your tables. Please edit your question to elaborate on the race condition you might have, maybe even with example data (and meaningful table names).

Comment: you mean insert with the same uuid? uuid collision's are very very very rare. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Comment: @Progman updated the question.